# How to check all checkboxes on selecting one in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
isCheckAll: false, 
 
 methods: {
     checkAll: function(){

      this.isCheckAll = !this.isCheckAll;
    },
    updateCheckall: function(){
      
         this.isCheckAll = true;
     
    },
```

```html
 <div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter">
                <input type="checkbox" id="three" class="vh-product" @click='checkAll()' v-model='isCheckAll' />
                <label class="productlist-specific" for="three"
                  > : 2011</label
                >
              </div>
 <div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter2">
                <input type="checkbox" id="four" class="vh-product"  @change='updateCheckall()'/>
                <label class="productlist-specific" for="four">E0A</label>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter3">
                <input type="checkbox" id="five" class="vh-product" @change='updateCheckall()'/>
                <label class="productlist-specific" for="five">BR</label>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter4">
                <input type="checkbox" id="six" class="vh-product"  @change='updateCheckall()'/>
                <label class="productlist-specific" for="six">E11350A</label>
              </div>
              <div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter5">
                <input type="checkbox" id="seven" class="vh-product" @change='updateCheckall()'>
                <label class="productlist-specific" for="seven">E0BR</label>
              </div>
```

How to select check and uncheck all checkboxes, on selecting one checkbox.

I don't know what stopping me to proceed, For every checkbox taken one @click and sub checkboxes also taken one @click. and then in js i am toggling that condition to check and uncheck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you had some problems with your logic, so let me explain this for you:

- You need to have a v-model on all of them, to be able to control state updates (whenever a user clicks something it needs to be updated).
- You don't need to have two methods for all of this, you can have just one to enable all of the checkboxes. The rest can be handled by v-model.

The following code will enable/disable all of the checkboxes by clicking the first one, and if you click the other ones, it'll just enable/disable that particular checkbox.

```html
<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkboxes[0]" v-on:click="checkAll()">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkboxes[1]">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkboxes[2]">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkboxes[3]">
</div>
```

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    // control the state of checkboxes
    checkboxes: [false, false, false, false]
  },
  methods: {
    checkAll: function(){
      for(let i = 1; i < this.checkboxes.length; i++){
        // update all of the checkboxes to the value of the first one.
        this.checkboxes[i] = !this.checkboxes[0];
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with multiple checkboxes, you should bind them to the same Array using v-model according to the Vue docs. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox

In your case, this means that you should have one array managing all the checkboxes except the one which controls selecting them all, that should be handled differently.
Each of those checkboxes should have a value binding as well, telling Vue which value they represent in the array.
You could also store all the possible checkbox values in an array which would help you reducing code duplication in your template.
You can render all 4 checkboxes which can be separately checked using a v-for loop, and manage them with the same v-model.

The checkbox controlling the "all checked" state should be managed with a different v-model. When that checkboxes value changes, we should check/uncheck all the other checkboxes, which can be done easily using a watcher.

Here's an example using this approach https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-dijkstra-fzkmn?file=/src/App.vue

```js
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: () => ({
    selectedValues: [],
    allChecked: false,
  }),
  computed: {
    isAllChecked() {
      return false;
    },
    allCheckboxOptions() {
      return [
        {
          label: "E0A",
          value: "four",
        },
        {
          label: "BR",
          value: "five",
        },
        {
          label: "E11350A",
          value: "six",
        },
        {
          label: "E0BR",
          value: "seven",
        },
      ];
    },
  },
  methods: {
    checkAll() {
      this.selectedValues = this.allCheckboxOptions.map(
        (option) => option.value
      );
    },
    checkNone() {
      this.selectedValues = [];
    },
  },
  watch: {
    allChecked(isAllChecked) {
      if (isAllChecked) {
        this.checkAll();
      } else {
        this.checkNone();
      }
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="checkbox-alignment-form-filter">
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        id="three"
        class="vh-product"
        v-model="allChecked"
      />
      <label class="productlist-specific" for="three"> : 2011</label>
    </div>
    <template v-for="(checkboxOption, index) in allCheckboxOptions">
      <div
        :key="checkboxOption.value"
        :class="`checkbox-alignment-form-filter${index + 2}`"
      >
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          :id="checkboxOption.value"
          :value="checkboxOption.value"
          v-model="selectedValues"
          class="vh-product"
        />
        <label class="productlist-specific" for="four">
          {{ checkboxOption.label }}
        </label>
      </div>
    </template>
    checked: {{ selectedValues }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem was your data handling.
i made you a playable example in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-thunder-lkd5t?file=/src/App.vue).

with this you are able to control the main checkbox bidirectional.

if all sub checkboxes are true the main checkbox will be set to true as well.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="checkbox-group">
      <div class="main-checkbox">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          :name="checkboxes.main.label"
          v-model="checkboxes.main.value"
          @input="toggleAllCheckboxes()"
        />
        <label :for="checkboxes.main.label">{{ checkboxes.main.label }}</label>
      </div>
      <div
        class="sub-checkbox"
        v-for="(checkbox, index) in checkboxes.sub"
        :key="index"
      >
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          :name="checkbox.label"
          v-model="checkbox.value"
        />
        <label :for="checkbox.label">{{ checkbox.label }}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: () => ({
    checkboxes: {
      main: {
        value: false,
        label: ":2011",
      },
      sub: [
        {
          value: false,
          label: "E0A",
        },
        {
          value: false,
          label: "BR",
        },
        {
          value: false,
          label: "E11350A",
        },
        {
          value: false,
          label: "E0BR",
        },
      ],
    },
  }),
  computed: {
    mainIsChecked: function () {
      return this.checkboxes.main.value;
    },
    allSubsAreChecked: function () {
      return this.checkboxes.sub.every((checkbox) => checkbox.value);
    },
  },
  watch: {
    allSubsAreChecked: function () {
      this.checkboxes.main.value = this.allSubsAreChecked;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    toggleAllCheckboxes() {
      for (const checkbox of this.checkboxes.sub) {
        checkbox.value = !this.mainIsChecked;
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```